# Error "; expected" in script tag of a vue file

Tags: vue.js

```
<script>
data() {
isShown: true
}
</script>
```

The closing parenthesis is underlined with an error message

> ; expected

I tried this:

```
<script>
data({
isShown: true
})
</script>
```

But no resolution

P.S. I used Vite to set Vue up

Comment: You are missing a return statement, should be: `data() { return { isShown: true }}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that you must be trying to learn Vue blindfolded. Even a cursory glance at [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html) or any tutorial should reveal the proper syntax for Vue `<script>`

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isShown: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Please read documentation or try Googling how to use a framework before posting questions about the fundamental basics.  StackOverflow is [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6225326) the best place for these types of questions.